# Mocking: Verify Static Void Method Is Called

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I am having trouble with the test cases for methods: deleteOldBermudaFolder and isExistingDirectory.
Below is the code:

```
class BermudaCacheDumpServiceImpl implements BermudaCacheDumpService {

    @Autowired
    PreferenceService preferenceService

    @Autowired
    FileUtils fileUtils

    static final String WORKING_DIR = 'bermudaCacheDumpWorkDir'
    static final String FOLDER_TO_DELETE = 'bermudaCacheDumpDeleteFolder'

    boolean isLandingStripAssembled(){
        boolean isLSAssembled
        File oldBermudaFolder = new File(workingDirectory + folderToDelete)

        deleteOldBermudaFolder(oldBermudaFolder)

        isLSAssembled = hasValidFiles()
        isLSAssembled
    }

    void deleteOldBermudaFolder(File oldBermudaFolder) throws IOException{
        if(isExistingDirectory(oldBermudaFolder)){
            fileUtils.deleteDirectory(oldBermudaFolder)
        }
        else{
            log.error("Unable to delete directory")
        }
    }

    boolean isExistingDirectory(File file){
        file.exists() && file.isDirectory()
    }

    boolean isExistingFile(File file){
        file.exists() && file.isFile()
    }

    private String getWorkingDirectory(){    preferenceService.getValue(WORKING_DIR)    }

    private String getFolderToDelete(){    preferenceService.getValue(FOLDER_TO_DELETE)    }
```

My testing cases:

```
class BermudaCacheDumpServiceImplTest extends GroovyTestCase{

    BermudaCacheDumpServiceImpl bermudaCacheDumpService
    PreferenceService mockPreferenceService
    FileUtils mockFileUtils

    void setUp(){
        mockPreferenceService = mock(PreferenceService) //Line 18
        mockFileUtils = mock(FileUtils)
        bermudaCacheDumpService = new BermudaCacheDumpServiceImpl(preferenceService: mockPreferenceService, fileUtils: mockFileUtils)
    }

    void testIsExistingFile()
    {
        File mockedFile = mock(File.class)
        when(mockedFile.exists()).thenReturn(true)
        when(mockedFile.isFile()).thenReturn(true)

        assert bermudaCacheDumpService.isExistingFile(mockedFile)
    }

    void testIsExistingDirectory(){
        File mockedFile = mock(File.class)
        when(mockedFile.exists()).thenReturn(true)
        when(mockedFile.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true)

        assert bermudaCacheDumpService.isExistingDirectory(mockedFile)
    }

    void testDeleteOldBermudaFolder(){
        def dummyFile = new File("/apps/Codes/PLS/LS/bermuda")
        File mockedFile = mock(File.class)

        when(bermudaCacheDumpService.isExistingDirectory(mockedFile)).thenReturn(true)
        bermudaCacheDumpService.deleteOldBermudaFolder(mockedFile)
        verify(bermudaCacheDumpService.fileUtils, times(1)).deleteDirectory(dummyFile)
    }
}
```

The issue:
When I comment out the testDeleteOldBermudaFolder() the entire test file runs with no errors. But the moment I uncomment testDeleteOldBermudaFolder() I get an error on testIsExistingDirectory()

All of the tests when run individually give no errors and show as passing but when run together as a unit with testDeleteOldBermudaFolder() uncommented, the testIsExistingDirectory() test fails.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

at com.thomsonreuters.legal.lpa.bermudacachedump.BermudaCacheDumpServiceImplTest.setUp(BermudaCacheDumpServiceImplTest.groovy:18)
```

From the error above it is saying that the CallSiteArray is not being verified but no where is that being called. Line 18 of the code points to the PreferenceService being made in SetUp(). From debugging, after running testDeleteOldBermudaFolder() and showing that it is correct it goes to run testIsExistingDirectory() and when it tries to mock up the PreferenceService it is unable too and claims it to be null.
Whenever the testIsExistingDirectory() test is uncommented the  testIsExistingDirectory() test always runs after it. I'm not sure why though.

Even the testIsExistingDirectory() test is failing and showing the error I don't believe that test is incorrect.
I believe this issue has to do with the testDeleteOldBermudaFolder() since it is the only test that causes problems with testIsExistingDirectory(). And it is the only one with the verify in it.

In my main code I am calling FileUtils.deleteDirectory which is a static void method.

I have started to look into PowerMockito but every example I have seen shows a method that returns a value and uses the when/do syntax. For this if the directory exists then I need to verify the FileUtils.deleteDirectory will be called. I need that verify statement.

**I'm looking for an explanation on why this specific mocking is not working? And I'm looking for an example on how to correctly mock FileUtils.deleteDirectory to verify that is being called.** Specifically the syntax.
Or looking for a workaround to verify FileUtils.

```
verify(fileUtils, times(1)).deleteDirectory(new File("/apps/Codes/PLS/LS/bermuda"))
```

Same error as above

```
verify(FileUtils, times(1)).deleteDirectory(dummyFile)
```

Same error as above

```
verify(bermudaCacheDumpService.fileUtils).deleteDirectory(dummyFile)
```

Same error as above

```
FileUtils fileUtils = mock(FileUtils.class)
verify(fileUtils, times(1)).deleteDirectory(dummyFile)
```

Same error as above

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(bermudaCacheDumpService.fileUtils, times(1)).deleteDirectory(dummyFile)
```

incorrect syntax - PowerMockito cannot be applied to FileUtils

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(FileUtils.class, times(1))
```

incorrect syntax - PowerMockito cannot be applied to FileUtils

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileUtils.class, { invocationOnMock ->
    assertEquals(dummyFile, invocationOnMock.getArgument(0, File.class))
    return null
})
```

I saw this on StackOverflow and tried it out. But the syntax is incorrect. It also doesn't help verify that the deletedirectory is called.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use mockito-inline to mock static methods like this:

```
try (MockedStatic<FileUtils> MockedStatic = mockStatic(FileUtils.class)) {

    MockedStatic
        .verify(() -> FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dummyFile), times(1));
}
```

Some examples here -> [mocking static methods](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods)